# Can some please tell me how to put curly braces around the real part in an equation?

Tags: delimiters

```
\begin{equation*}
  f \in S\mbox{*} \iff Re({\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)})>0 
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you need both tall round parentheses and tall curly braces? Or just one or the other? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  f \in S^* \iff \mathrm{Re}\left(\biggl\{\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}\biggr\}\right)>0 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]